# Do I need @Transient annotation on un-mapped super-class attributes?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, transient

OK, here's the simple example:

I have an abstract super class defined thus:

```
abstract public class AbstractSuperEntity {

    private char someFlag;

    public void setSomeFlag(char flagValue) {
        this.someFlag = flagValue;
    }

    public char getSomeFlag() {
        return this.someFlag;
    }
 }
```

which all my `@Entity` classes inherit from. An example might be:

```
@Entity
@Table("SOME_ENTITY")
public class SomeEntity extends AbstractSuperEntity {

    @Column(name="ID");
    private Long id;

    etc.

}
```

Does the `someFlag` attribute in `AbstractSuperEntity` need to have the `@Transient`?

I've tried it with and without, and it doesn't seem to make any difference. But I'm just scared I'm missing something.

---

**EDIT** Thanks for all the quick answers.

A colleague has also pointed me to the JPA Tutorial at JPalace.org, and in particular the page on [ORM and JPA Concepts](http://www.jpalace.org/docs/tutorials/jee/jpa_2.html) which has the following section:

> **Non-Entity Superclasses**
>
> Entities may also extend non-entity superclasses. These superclasses can be either abstract or concrete. The state of non-entity superclasses is always non-persistent. Thus, any state inherited from the non-entity superclass by an entity class is non-persistent.
>
> Similarly to mapped superclasses, non-entity superclasses may not be used subject to queries. *Mapping and relationship annotation present in a non-entity superclasses are ignored*. Again, this is beacause there is no correponding database table to which the querying operations or relationships can be applied.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the `@Transient` annotation is not needed, as your `AbstractSuperEntity` is neither a [`MappedSuperClass`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/MappedSuperclass.html), nor an [`Entity`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/Entity.html). You have to annotate it with one of those annotations if you want it to contain mapping information (that is inherited).

Comment: Thanks Andrei. Although James answered the question first, I'm awarding you the answer as yours is concise, definitive and has some useful links.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to disagree with Jukka and say that you don't need the annotation. It should be obvious from your configuration that the superclass isn't mapped by Hibernate, and that as far as Hibernate is concerned, your superclass doesn't even exist.

If you then go and start marking fields on the superclass as `@Transient` I would infer that the superclass as a whole is mapped by Hibernate but this particular field isn't. If its the only field on the superclass, I start to wonder why this class is mapped by Hibernate, go looking for the superclass mapping, get confused when I can't find it etc etc etc...

More broadly speaking, if I notice the presence of any JPA/Hibernate annotations I automatically assume that the class is mapped by your persistence provider, but at the end of the day, its your project and your decision as to what makes the code clearer.

Comment: Thanks James, I feel the same as you about not having anything that might confuse future developers. In our case, the abstract super class was created by a previous employee and he put the `@Transient` annotations on its attributes. As you say, I was confused as to why these annotations were there. They're gone now! :-)

Answer (score 0):

If that property is globally not persistent, then adding the @Transient annotation will not hurt and will in fact make it explicitly transient for future readers of your code.